# Update Subscriber Status Marketing Cloud SOAP API - OverallStatus Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, subscriber

I'm trying to update a Subscriber status that belongs to a list to "Unsubscribed" value, even for this or other calls (Except get List subscribers) I'm getting the Overall Status as "Error".

Here's my request:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Header>
      <fueloauth>MyValidAccessToken</fueloauth>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <UpdateRequest>
         <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
            <Attributes>
               <Name>Status</Name>
               <Value>Unsubscribed</Value>
            </Attributes>
            <SubscriberKey>email_I_want_to_remove@s.co</SubscriberKey>
            <Lists>
               <ID>19</ID>
            </Lists>
         </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

And this is the response I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:26eff0b0-ce15-494f-a36a-cff480f4a085</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:db9863fc-c240-42bd-b944-aab741977b87</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-6acc57a7-22f4-42ff-afcb-ded1eef6fd0c">
                <wsu:Created>2018-11-27T12:42:49Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2018-11-27T12:47:49Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>fa257200-ef75-460d-96f6-b68f67ec3548</RequestID>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is anything I maybe missing on my request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi all seems all the issue was because the "SOAPAction" Header, depending of which action are you executing the header we need to set (Retrieve,Delete,Create).

Here a success sample call for Create:

**URL**: https://yourmarketingcloudurl.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx

**POST**

**Headers**:
SOAPAction:Create
Accept:text/xml
Content-type:text/xml
charset:UTF-8

Body:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <Header>
          <fueloauth>your_access_token</fueloauth>
     </Header>
     <Body>
          <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true">
                </PartnerKey>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true">
                </ObjectID>
                <EmailAddress>email@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
                <SubscriberKey>email@gmail.com</SubscriberKey>
                <Lists>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ID>ListID</ID>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                </Lists>
            </Objects>
         </CreateRequest>
     </Body>
</Envelope>
```